# NHibernate parent-child relationship: does NH update parents in entity cache?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, parent-child, second-level-cache

If I update a child in a parent-child relationship, the child gets updated
in the L2 cache. But what about the parent? Is it possible to do this without
hitting the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L2 entity cache is updated when the corresponding entity is updated and the corresponding transaction is committed. Relationships don't matter.

Comment: Thanks, Diego. Does NH track relationships? Is the parent(s) known at runtime?

Comment: Also, does this mean that if the parent is in the cache, that it is now stale?

Comment: @Jacko, why would it be stale? I have the feeling that you have some misconceptions on how the L2 cache works... I suggest that you post in the nhusers group, which is better suited for open discussions.

Comment: oh, right, the parent has a reference to the child. Thanks, will try nhusers.